# Stack interpreter option - Add an external dependency

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, haskell-turtle

I'm making a script with [Turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle) and I need a dependency from GitHub. I saw that you can add such a dependency when you make a project by putting this in your `stack.yaml`:

```
packages:
- location:
    git: https://github.com/githubuser/reponame.git
    commit: somecommitID
```

But is it possible to add it via the command line?

This is the command line used to run the script:

```
stack --resolver lts-3.2 --install-ghc runghc --package turtle
```

**Edit**:

These are the first lines of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-3.1 --install-ghc runghc --package turtle

import Turtle
...
```

Comment: `stack runghc` is excuted in the global project. You can add the dependency to the `stack.yaml` of your global project.

Comment: Or you can put a `stack.yaml` file along with your script and refer this config file in your script by `--stack-yaml ./your-stack.yaml` to achieve some portability, but the additional package still have to be installed in your global project I guess.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have a global project. I'd like to execute this script as a standalone program, as you can do with a normal turtle script.

Comment: That's weird. When I run `stack runghc` I see "Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config, using resolver: lts-5.1 from implicit global project's config file:\path\to\global\stack.yaml" in my console, are you sure the behavior of your stack is different?

Answer (score 3):

We do not support all of stack.yaml options on the commandline.  I recommend putting a stack.yaml somewhere.  If you don't want to just put it in the same folder as the script, use "--stack-yaml"